# Nice GUI ide for developing IPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ide

I am developing an IPhone app and I'm slowly coming to the realisation that I will need to use Objective-c. Is there a nice visual IDE which I can use which has a preview mode and all the nice things like that so I can rapidly prototype and develop the app? (I have access to very powerful macs and pcs and I don't mind paying up to $3000 for the IDE)

Comment: Realistically speaking, Xcode is your only option.

Comment: If you have that much budget, here's an idea: spend it building your own.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't know I could hire Objective-C developers so cheap as $3000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's so bad about Xcode and iOS Simulator? With [Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html), Interface Builder is built right into the IDE and is considered the designer component of the IDE (and IMHO also one of the best IDE designer components I've used). Furthermore, you can run your code and preview your app live using the simulator.

Oh and Xcode 4 is only $4.99 on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214?mt=12).

Comment: Jetbrains is an IDE written in Java and they have just released an IDE called AppCode which allows you to develop Objective-C programs

Comment: Why do so many people feel the need to defend Xcode? Can't we be honest about it? It has essentially no refactoring support, no code generation (any time I add an instance variable, I have to manually add the property declaration, the synthesize declaration and the release call in dealloc), it lacks the autofix ability available in many other editors...I use it daily and it works well but it's foolish to pretend that it's not years behind other modern IDE's. Any serious refactorings or code organizations require manually muddling through my code and gettiing all the details right.